# PHP - Best way to get meta data from comments

Tags: php, html, api, meta-tags

PHP has a function called [get_meta_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) which can read meta tags of HTML files. However, as far as I know there is no standard way to define meta tags for PHP files. The de facto solution seems to be to add comment to the top of the file like so:

```
<?php

     # Author: Ood
     # Description: Hello World

?>
```

Is there any way to read these "meta tags" with PHP similar to the way `get_meta_tags` works using the default PHP library? Preferably without parsing the entire file with `file_get_contents` followed by a regex for best performance. If not, maybe someone knows of a better solution to add meta data capabilities to PHP files. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just curious why you would want to get some meta data from a PHP file? Can you explain why you would want to do this?

Comment: @scunliffe Sure! I have a folder of PHP plugins which should be listed on a dashboard. At the moment I can only display the file name and thought it would be better for usability to add a name and description to each plugin file.

Comment: I've found it's more common the have a DocBlock at the top of the file. This is part of [the convention](https://developer.wordpress.org/coding-standards/inline-documentation-standards/php/#6-file-headers) for Wordpress as well. phpDoc is a fairly standardized format and there are quite a few parsers available for it.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Cool, this looks very promising and I will read up on it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: If you do end up deciding to parse it yourself, you could use `fopen()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and `fgets()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) to read only one line at a time. Then you could scan the first 2 or 3 lines looking for the comments, and then continue scanning until the end of the comments. That wouldn't load the entire file into memory, and you could look through the files more efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *our project* we are happy with the standard `JavaDoc` that was adopted by [PHPDoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPDoc) using the `@field` syntax as you might know it from any PHP function or class definition. This is pretty fine readable using the [PHPDocumenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpDocumentor).

In our adoption we use the very first multi-line comment, ie anyting between `/**` and closing tag `*/`, using the JavaDoc style to describe all the details about the current script.

So to adopt your example in our project we would have following syntax:

```
<?php
/**
* @author Ood
* @desc  Hello World
*/
```

Of course you may end up with your custom function reading the beginning of the php file parsing just the very first multi-line comment to get the script description aka meta tags.